Movie about a psychic teenage girl going to haunted house
When I was a kid, I always watched my mother's collection of horror movies when she wasn't home. I remember one particular movie about a group of people (including a psychic teenage girl who doesn't talk much) going into a haunted house, kind of a huge mansion! Its a huge old house/mansion and in one scene there is a painting of an old lady suddenly turning into a skeleton-ish ghost! If I'm not mistaken, the reason they are there is because one of the main characters wants to photograph ghosts. I've been trying to remember the movie, but can't find anything that reminds me of the film. Its a 1990-2009 film. Unsure of the specific year though.

Might be "Rose Red" which was actually a mini-series from 2002.

thank u! i have been looking for this for years!

You are looking for Stephen King's Rose Red from 2002.  This was actually a mini-series.
The story is about a mansion in Seattle, Washington that is cursed because it is built on an ancient Indian burial ground.
It features an autistic girl, Annie Wheaton who also has psychic abilities.

Dr. Joyce Reardon, an unorthodox university psychology professor,
  leads a team of psychics to the massive and antiquated Seattle mansion
  known as Rose Red in an attempt to record data which would constitute
  scientific proof of paranormal phenomena. The mansion is publicly
  thought to be haunted, as at least 23 people have either disappeared
  or died there and the interior of the house appears to change or
  increase in size, yet only from the inside. Reardon's team awakens the
  evil spirit possessing the house, leading to several deaths and the
  revelation of the mansion's deadly secrets.
The young autistic girl Annie Wheaton (played as a child by Kristen Fischer, and later as a teenager by Kimberly J. Brown) is
  drawing a picture of a house as her parents and older sister, Rachel
  (Melanie Lynskey), argue outside her room. As she draws lines down
  over the house in her picture, rocks fall through the roof of an
  identical house belonging to an elderly couple down the street whose
  dog had bitten Annie, severely damaging the building.

